# TFS 2013 resolve conflicts error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I got quite few items are list on my Pending changes Resolve conflicts, 
however, when I undo all my pending changes, 
those conflicts are still there, and when I try to resolve them manully, it said my local version is 0, and my local change is indetical with the server change, when I try to take server version 
it pop up the error string must have a least one character, Prameter name: item,

My TFS is TFS2013 RTM 
vs version bothe VS2013 and VS2012
thanks any suggestion or advice, 
kind regards

Comment: You should update to TFS 2013.4 to stay current for bug fixes and updates...

Comment: well. 2013.4 is CTP version yet, we need deploy more stable version

Comment: 2013.4 was released 3 weeks ago mate...and 2013.3 has been out for over 3 months...

Answer (score 1):

Undo all Pending Changes, make sure there are no pending changes under the Excluded Items section, then do a Get Latest.  That should bring your workspace up to date, and there should be no conflicts.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for your kind inputs,yes I did undo all the pending changes and try to get latest and also do the get specific version to overwrite my local instance, well it does't help, and still keep same number of conflicts with the  error string must have a least one character, Prameter name: item,any further advice?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something similar in VS2015. No changes in my workspace but there is a conflict that can't be cleared. As best I can tell there is an entry in an internal conflict table.

I used the tf command to clear conflicts. Don't do this to clear a real conflict.

command documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yw3tcdy.aspx

1. Open Developer Command Prompt
2. Change directory to conflict location: `cd <path/to/conflict>`
3. To resolve one conflict, replace `.\ConflictFile.txt` with your file name:
   `tf resolve .\ConflictFile.txt \auto:DeleteConflict`
   or
   To resolve all conflicts: `tf resolve \auto:DeleteConflict`

Comment: According to MS Documentation use slash, not backslash: `tf resolve /auto:DeleteConflict`